# Find $x=0$ for $f'(x)=(2x^4-3x^2)/(2x^2-1)^2$

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

$f'(x)=(2x^4-3x^2)/((2x^2-1)^2$

$(2x^4-3x^2)/((2x^2-1)^2)=0$ $=>$ $(2x^4-3x^2)=(2x^2-1)^2$

$=>$ $(2x^4-3x^2)=4x^4-4x^2+1$ which is simplified to

$2x^4-x^2+1=0$

how do I find where $x=0$, I thought about breaking out an $x^2$ but that doesn't since I have a $1$ too

Comment: $$\frac{2x^4-3x^2}{(2x^2-1)^2}=0$$ does not imply $2x^4 - 3x^2 = (2x^2-1)^2$. If you did want to solve the quartic, then set $u = x^{2}$ and apply the quadratic formula to $u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $$f'(x)=0$$ we get
$$2x^4-3x^2=0$$ since $$0\cdot (2x^2-1)^2=0$$
and you have to solve $$x^2(2x^2-3)=0$$